# SQL to handle multiple AND conditions

Tags: oracle, relational-division

I have the following data:

| Institution_no | Cred_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

I have a list box so the user can select multiple Cred_type, they want to be able to select either OR or AND conditions.

For the OR I have like this AND CRED_TYPE IN (1,2)

For the AND, I am really scratching my head.  What they are saying is they want a list of institutions that have cred type 1 and cred_type 2.   Perhaps I'm not thinking clearly but this is row by row, so doing this would lead to no results.

AND cred_type = 1
AND cred_type = 2  -- you can't have a single row have two different values, this would return no results.

They require that the user can select 10, 20, or more, so writing out a bunch of code for each and combining them all would be really tough - but this is the only thought I had so far.  It would be like this

```
Select institution_no from table where cred_type = 1
UNION 
Select institution_no from table where cred_type = 2
```

-- this would combine both and get me what I want, but you could imagine all the code for 10 or 20 of these.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Good idea but unfortunately they have multiple duplications so sometimes inst 1 could have 3 rows of cred_type 1.  So just doing having ... = 2 will not work.

Comment: See Erwin's answer here: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)** where there are 10+ methods to write this kind of query (and performance testing in Postgres). The problem is called (and we have a tag for it): [tag:relational-division]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [HAVING](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj14854.html) clause.

For example:
If you have  a list of institutions that have cred type 1,2,3,4,5,6 you could try something like:

```
select institution_no 
from table 
where cred_type in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
group by institution_no
having count(distinct cred_type)=6;
```

**EDIT: Query used by `OP`**

```
with cte as ( 
             select distinct institution_no, 
                    CERT_TYPE 
             from credentialing 
             where CERT_TYPE in (1,2)
             ) 
select institution_no, 
       count(institution_no) 
from cte 
group by institution_no 
having count(institution_no) = 2;
```

Comment: `having count(distinct cred_type)=6` to deal with duplicates.

Comment: @ErgestBasha thanks so much.  The way I did it was this - this gets rid of the duplicate rows

`with cte as (select distinct institution_no, CERT_TYPE from credentialing where CERT_TYPE in (1,2))
select institution_no, count(institution_no) from cte group by institution_no having count(institution_no) = 2;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution where you could build off of your OR query for the AND query:

```
select distinct t2.institution_no from
(select t1.institution_no, count(distinct t1.cred_type) as cnt from
(select institution_no, cred_type from table_name where cred_type in (1,2,3,6,7)) t1
group by t1.institution_no) t2
where cnt=5
```

- t1 is simply the OR query, but also prints out cred_type
- t2 calculates the number of different cred_types, within the
  acceptable creds
- the final table prints out the institutions that have all of those
  creds

That way you only need to update the list of credentials, and the count when they request a bunch of cred_types. If you don't even want to update the count number each time, you could make the list of cred_types a variable, and place it in t1, along with calculating the length of the variable in the where statement.

Comment: the other solution actually looks better, but you could still leverage my variable idea if you'd like to cut down on changes to the query each time.

Comment: This is really clever!